# Hide index.php in URL when posting data to the site

Tags: html, apache, server

I have an index file in `www.myserver.com/download/index.php`
When the user visits `www.myserver.com/download` the `index.php` is automatically loaded, but doesn't show up in the browser URL box (=ok)

Now I need to post data to the same `index.php` file.

When I do it the following way, index.php is showing up in the browser URL after posting (=bad).

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="testpost" value="TEST" />
</form>
```

And when I do it the following way, the POST data gets lost (=bad).

```
<form action="../download" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="testpost" value="TEST" />
</form>
```

How can I hide the index.php after posting data to it?
The solution should not hide all `index.php` on the whole server, but only this specific one.

I tried to make a .htaccess rule to hide the index.php in the "download" directory, but my knowledge is way to bad to get it working.

Comment: It sounds like your server is sending a redirect (which turns POST into GET).  Make it not do that.

Comment: I have only FTP access and can't change apache settings because it is restricted from my provider. I tried to make a htaccess rule, but I didn't get it working...my knowledge is way to bad :-(